# Jquery display:none, display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to set an element from `display: none` to `display: inline-block`
when clicking on another element.

Jquery always detects it `display: none`

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#click").click(function () {
            if($("#show").css('display','none')) {
                $('#show').css('display','inline-block');
            } else {
                $('#show').css('display','none');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#show {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="click">
    Click
</div>
<div id="show">
    Text
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67bbLm39/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` statement is wrong,

```
if($("#show").css('display','none'))
```

You are assigning the css property to the `show` element in your `if` statement, use `.is(':visible')` instead.

```
if(!$("#show").is(':visible'))
```

Comment: This answer explains what's wrong instead of just giving the "fixed" code. +1

Comment: Well I rather know what's wrong and what has to be replaced

Answer (score 1):

Update your `if()` to use the `is(':visible')` function:

```
var displayType = ( ! $("#show").is(':visible') ) ? 'inline-block' 
                                                  : 'none';

$('#show').css('display', displayType);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/67bbLm39/2/)

Comment: Your fiddle is running onload - that can't be right

Comment: You have a fiddle set to run onload, that will wrap it in $(function() {} , then your code is wrapped in $(function($) {} and inside that you have $(document).ready...

Comment: @mplungjan I just updated the OP's Fiddle. Didn't change the options. Oh, and `onload` !== `$(function() {  })`. That's a wrapper for DOMReady.

Comment: Still a waste of event handlers

Answer (score 1):

Like many jQuery functions, [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) has two different behavior, based on the parameters you pass.

If you pass just the first parameter (the css property), it returns the value of the css property.

If you pass the css property and the value, it set the value and returns the actual jQuery object.

Try this:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        //Get the div in jquery object.
        var div = $("#show");
        //Determine the actual value of the display.
        var display = div.css('display');

        //Determine the desired value.
        if (display == 'none')
            display = 'inline-block';
        else
            display = 'none';

        //Change the value
        div.css('display', display);

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```